# GSON Output is String

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm learning Java during my studies and I'm having problems converting a String to JSON using GSON. The following code returns specified data from a weather data DB, which I can enter - this works so far. However, the task now is that I save the output in a JSON format, and this is not working.

I appreciate any help - thank you! :)

```
public static void getInformationFromCity() throws Exception {
    int city = readAndCheckIfCityIsValid();
    System.out.println("input startdate ");
    LocalDate startDate = readAndCheckIfStartDateIsValid();
    System.out.println("input enddate ");
    LocalDate endDate = readAndCheckIfEndDateIsValid();

    List<WeatherData> list = dummy1.getInformationFromCity(city, startDate, endDate);

    System.out.println("\n weatherdata for " + city + " in the timeperiod between" + startDate + " and "
            + endDate + " are:\n");

    for (WeatherData i : list) {

        String output = ("Date: " + i.getLastUpdateTime() + " Temperature: " + i.getCurrentTemperatureCel()
                + "°C" + " , Pressure: " + i.getPressure() + " hPa" + " und humidity: " + i.getHumidity()
                + " %");
        System.out.println(output);
    
        // to file
        String json = new Gson().toJson(output);

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("a02.json");
        writer.write(json);
        writer.close();

    }
}
```

And the output in my file is a String instead of JSON

- "Datum: 2022-02-03T23:37:38 Temperatur: 4.0°C , Luftdruck: 1023 hPa
  und Feuchtigkeit: 83 %"

Comment: You're converting your string to JSON. What output did you expect.

Comment: I must add that another method works perfectly

   List<City> list = dummy1.getCities();
   for (City i : list) {
    System.out.println(i.getName());
    Writer writer = new FileWriter("a01.json");
    gson.toJson(list, writer);
    writer.close();
   }

With the output (example results): [{"name":"Lausanne","zip":1000},{"name":"Geneva","zip":1200}]

Comment: You're explicitly formatting your data to a string, and then asking GSON to encode that string value as JSON - which it's doing. If you don't want all the data in a single string to start with, you shouldn't have that `String output = ...` line that *does* put all the data in  a single string...

Comment: And yes, your "other method" works because it's *not* formatting the data into a single string before getting GSON involved.

Comment: Have you tried `String json = new Gson().toJson(i);` instead, so that it encodes the `WeatherData` instead of the string?

Comment: thanks for your quick reply Jon!

After changing it to String json = new Gson().toJson(i);

I unfortunately receive the following error;
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.time.LocalDate java.time.LocalDateTime.date accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.time" to unnamed module @1165b38

Comment: I need to display my output visibly on the UI, which I do with sysout - so I thought, I would convert this to a string and then output this. Maybe this is not an efficient idea and you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Write a type adapter and mappingClass:

define class to map json / gson

```
class GsonMap{
// define your object
}
```

define TypeAdapter for parsing LocalTime

```
public class GsonParseLocalDateTime extends TypeAdapter<LocalTime>{
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, LocalTime value) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

        return LocalTime.parse(in.nextString();
    }

}
```

define TypeAdapter for parsing LocalDateTime

```
public class GsonParseLocalTime extends TypeAdapter<LocalDateTime>{
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, LocalDateTime value) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {

        return LocalDateTime.parse(in.nextString();
    }

}
```

create gson builder

```
Gson g = new GsonBuilder()
.registerTypeAdapter(java.time.LocalDateTime.class, new gsonDateTimeParser())
.registerTypeAdapter(java.time.LocalTime.class, new gsonTimeParser())
.create();
```

map your json string

```
g.fromJson(output, GsonMap);
```